# Making Dynamodb update_item idempotent - List Attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I would like to make my update_item operation idempotent. I have an attribute of type list, and I would like to add a element to list only if not exists. I imagine that i need to use: `ConditionExpression`

```
uptd = 'SET status_pedido_disponiveis = list_append(if_not_exists(status_pedido_disponiveis, :empty_list), :my_value)'
attr={ ":my_value": {"L": [{"S": xml }]}, ":empty_list":{"L": [] } }
self.dynamodb.update_item(TableName=self.table_name, Key={'order_id':{'S': order_id}}, 
                          UpdateExpression=uptd, 
                          ExpressionAttributeValues=attr
                          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
uptd = 'SET status_pedido_disponiveis = list_append(if_not_exists(status_pedido_disponiveis, :empty_list), :my_value)'
attr={ ":my_value": {"L": [{"S": xml }]}, ":empty_list":{"L": [] }, ':xml_content': {"S": xml } }
self.dynamodb.update_item(TableName=self.table_name, Key={'order_id':{'S': order_id}}, 
                          UpdateExpression=uptd, 
                          ExpressionAttributeValues=attr,
                          ConditionExpression = "not contains (status_pedido_disponiveis, :xml_content)"
                          )
```